# How to generate Transactions per Second graph, with the transaction controller only without including the child request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have run a JMeter script in the command line and exported the result in the .jtl format.  I have multiple samples under Transaction Controller, when I imported the .jtl in the aggregate report, and saved the table data in CSV, it is showing individual samples instead of showing the overall response time of the transaction controller.

I wanted to generate the graph for `Transactions per Second`, with the transaction controller only without including the child request.

I have tried:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\test-result-1.png --input-jtl E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\scriptresults.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 800 --height 600
```

It generated the graph as shown below which is hardly understandable.

[image]

I have the script structured as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to named parent transaction controler with a pattern like :
P01_SIGN-IN
P02_ADMIN_DASHBOARD
P03_APPLY

Then filtred with a regular expression P[0-9]+*.* (start with 'P' and 1 or more digit and '*' and others characters) and include-label-regex true

JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\test-result-1.png --include-labels P[0-9]+_.* --include-label-regex true --input-jtl E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\scriptresults.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 1024--height 800

Answer (score 0):

Just add `--include-labels` parameter and list all your Transaction Controller names there:

```
--include-labels sign-in,admin-dashboard,apply
```

full command just in case:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\test-result-1.png --include-labels sign-in,admin-dashboard,apply --input-jtl E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\scriptresults.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 800 --height 600
```

More information:

- [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool Usage and Parameters](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/#Usage-and-Parameters)
- [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

---

Wouldn't it be easier to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) instead?

Comment: I was looking for HTML reporting but how could it be done from the command line?

Comment: `jmeter -g E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\scriptresults.jtl -f -o E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\Data\Jmeterlog\HTMLRESULTS`

Comment: I have tried generating the HTML results, got the error, that says: An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message : `Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 1 is not equal to fixed size 5
errorlevel=1`